# How i create an app which run in system mode

Tags: salesforce1-app

Requirement:

I want to create an app which update the user information like profile, email,license etc.

For the above requirement modify-all permission  is required, but i want to do this without any dependency of an logged-in user means in system-mode context.

Please suggest some ideas.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Have you already tried something?

Comment: i tried visual flow and process-builder but i get to know that visual flow run's in a user-mode and process-builder doesn't support screen. only we can execute the auto-flow(which doesn't have screen to take the input from the user).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to build an app that works around the core platform security mechanisms. As someone who uses Salesforce a lot I would be appalled if that was possible.

All you can do is make it clear in your UI and documentation that your code can *only* be run successfully by a user that has the modify-all permission and if a user does not report that gracefully.